# Visual Studio Toolbox Not Including User Controls from Another Project from Same Solution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have looked everywhere and cannot find a solution.  My problem has the following elements:

I have a Visual Studio Solution (Visual Studio 2013) with several projects.

- One project ("Control Project") has several user controls I built.
- Other projects ("Other Control Projects") contain various open source controls.
- Another project (the "Problem Project") references the Control Project and the Other Control Projects.

The Visual Designer toolbox shows the Other Control Project controls perfectly in my Problem Project.
The Visual Designer fails to show the Control Project controls in my Problem Project.

I have tried:
1. Making sure the option to auto-populate the toolbox is checked.
2. Rebuilding the solution
3. Resetting the toolbox
4. Ensuring the access modifiers for the controls are Public.

If I "Choose Items", I can add the Control Project controls to the Problem Project by selected the .exe but this seems like a hack and also has caused other problems that are difficult to define.

Anybody have any clues on what may be wrong with either my Problem Project or my Control Project?

Comment: No responses here but wanted to update this by basically saying I solved this by referencing the .exe though the solution seems dirty since the exe in in the debug/release folder but it seems to do the job well enough I suppose.  In general, its taught me to stay away from user controls from outside the project I'm working in.

Comment: Close and reopen VS 2013 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

That answer might be a bit late but I recently had the same Problem.
For me it was a Problem with missing DLLs. 
I have a nearly simular Soloution like you.

- A Library providing selfmade UserControls
- Another project ("Problem Project") that references the Control Library

The problem occurred when I recently switched from VS2008 to VS2013 and from .NET Framework 3.5 to .NET Framework 4.5. The cause of the Problem for me seems to be with Crystal Reports references. In my Library project I have a Class that inherits from *CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass*. This Class I provide as a control in the Toolbox. When I open the Library Project itself (not as a Subproject) and open a Form to load the Toolbox I got the following Error: *Failed to create ToolboxItem of type: CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.ReportToolboxItem, CrystalDecsions.VSDesigner*.

After I knew this I found out, that I have to copy some Librarys, in my case

- **CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll**
- **CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll**
- **CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner**

to *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE* (found it here:[Can't add project controls to the Visual Studio Toolbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/239c2505-8502-4391-807e-887338b1cf02/cant-add-project-controls-to-the-visual-studio-toolbox?forum=vssetup))

To me it seems like VS Toolbox starts to create the Controls and gets an Error at one of them and stops to fill the Toolbox. In my case the problem might be, that I reference old CR Librarys (v12.x) which work with CLR 2.0 and .NET Framework 2.0 - 3.5 and I compile my project with .NET Framework 4.5 which works with CLR 4.0. It looks like the old Librarys are not supported in .NET 4.x. If I use this Workaround the Toolbox works fine for me.

Greetings

btw. sorry for the patchy english ;-)